# Spring Data Mongodb - findBy query with OR clause on same field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm working on mongo with spring data and using the query "findBy" based on property fields.

My goal will be find same value across multiple properties by OR clause like this:

```
List<Event> findByCreatorOrOrganizersOrGuests(User user);
```

this query involves 3 properties: "creator", "organizers" and "guests" that are a single value (creator) and 2 lists (organizers and guests) that contains the same class type (User)

at compile time I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!
```

Do I need to repeat the same parameter 3 times? There's no workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The using of Mongo queries for lists are not so efficient even if you define it with an index.

Another important thing is that the query:

```
List<Event> findByCreatorOrOrganizersOrGuests(User user);
```

includes some syntax errors (The MongoDB expects to get 3 parameters as variables int the ( ) relatively to the findBy keys, the return value should be inserted into a list object, and I am not sure that the Or in the find query is legal syntax.

As a concept the DB documents should have a good ability to be searched, cause it is the most expensive action.

When find using [OR in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) the direct query should looks like that:

def events =  find({ $or: [ { user.username: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )

While [searching in a list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) this is should be different, so please follow the links I attached.

When I try to think of the use you are looking for, I would suggest a different aspect. If the events is what interest you please read about the [AbstractPersistenceEventListener](http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/event/AbstractPersistenceEventListener.html). By define the appropriate

```
void onPostInsert(entity) {}
void onPostUpdate(entity) {}
void onPostDelete(entity) {}
```

You get all the events for each of the objects you want to listen to.

Here are 2 a great examples:

- [Example 1](https://github.com/pledbrook/spring-data-mapping/blob/master/spring-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/datastore/mapping/engine/event/AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java)
- [Example 2](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/3.0.2.RELEASE&path=/Source%20Packages/org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event/AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java)